# Creating custom polygon symbol using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, symbology, features

How can I create a custom polygon symbol? I already played with layering the symbol levels to no avail. I think that I need something a little more advanced than that.

I'd Like to get something that looks just like this.

I have also tried inserting this JPEG for the symbol but it creates a mosaic of images rather than one.

The outer edge represents the edge of a well pad. The circle in the center is supposed to represent a well head.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some screen caps of the undesirable behavior? I think that would make what you are trying to do clearer.

Comment: Do you want a custom polygon *fill* symbol, or a custom polygon symbol for a legend? I'm not sure what the image is supposed to represent (ie what is the outer boundary of 'a' polygon in the image).

Comment: I would like a custom polygon fill where the entire image posted is the fill. The lines and circle within the image are there for appearance.